# Чай — напиток(,) снимающий / который снимает усталость

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

Нужна запятая? Важно не то, что чай — напиток, — важно, что он снимает усталость:

`Чай — напиток(,) снимающий учталость.`

А если так ли?

`Чай — напиток(,) который снимает усталость.`

Comment: Что минусуем?.. Поясните, пожалуйста.  Это вопрос о соответствии  пауз, логических ударений и знаков препинания.  Хороший вопрос, Максим, голос от меня. Семантически значимое слово подчеркивается ударением.

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо, Sharon))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*ЧАй — // напиток, / **снимающий устАлость**.*

*ЧАй — // напиток, / **который снимает устАлость**.*

Интонация **одинаковая**, как и знаки препинания.

Почему? Здесь как бы два **семантических и интонационных блока**, отношения между ними обозначены тире и подчеркнутой паузой. Вторая пауза уходит **не второй план**, она меньше по длительности, менее значима.

В каждом сложном предложении происходит подобная **перестройка** в пользу **основной структуры**.

Логически **выделено** последнее слово **"усталость"**, что видно по схеме.

Comment: По поводу интонации согласен, а почему вхождения в состав сказуемого не может быть?

Comment: Ударение уходит в конец приведенного предложения.  Сравнить: ЧАй – это напиток снимАющий усталость, но отнюдь не расслаблЯющий.  Определительный оборот не входит в состав сказуемого, но тесно с ним связан.  Поэтому не обособляется как смысловой центр высказывания.

Answer (score 0):

"Снимает усталость" - это проверено. Однако люди разные.
"Который снимает усталость" - один из напитков, которые снимают усталость. И здесь, как пойдёт - одному "да", другому "нет".

Comment: А это вы о чем? Вопрос был о запятых в двух приведенных моделях со сходной семантикой. Одинаковые знаки или нет?

Comment: Важно не то, что напиток, а то, что снимает. Снимает - вера в первом случае.

Comment: Разная семантика? Допустим. Вы про запятые рассказывайте: как разная  (с вашей точки зрения) семантика влияет на постановку знаков.  "Нужна запятая?"  Это основной вопрос.  И метки: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот.

Comment: Когда мне отвечаете, не пишите больше иностранных слов. А в данном случае, не запятые указывают на проверенное утверждение.

Comment: Не пишите?  В повел.  наклонении и без "пожалуйста"? Иностранные слова? Извините, не буду больше беспокоить.